# WFS, python and updating

Tags: python, wfs, change-detection

I'm trying to develop a script, something that can be run every hour/day/week etc that will look at some shapefiles (initially downloaded from a WFS) compare them to the WFS and download and append any changes.

I have absolutely no idea how to start developing something like this, i'm not even sure if python is the right thing. I have looked rather extensively online for help with this and the best I came up with was this website (http://geopython.github.io/OWSLib/#wfs) but there is nothing on WFS in it, which isn't helpful.

I found the documentation for WFS be that wasnt particularly helpful for me. My background is primarily Geography, geology and basic computer science. I've worked with JS, HTML, PHP, CSS, Python but am in no way a developer.

If anyone is able to walk me through the steps to beginning to work with WFS outside of ArcMap that would be amazing.

Comment: Are you looking to develop this using ESRI's arcpy or another GIS python platform?

Comment: That I'm not sure. I'd like to lean towards ESRI as they'll be able to offer more support etc. But if there's a better alternative then I'm happy to give it a go.

Answer (score 1):

OWSLib supports WFS even if the website doesn't necessarily reflect this (documentation help is appreciated!).  Check the [WFS doctests](https://github.com/geopython/OWSLib/tree/master/tests/doctests) for examples.

A more complete implementation is [pywoudc](https://github.com/woudc/pywoudc), which uses OWSLib's WFS support to provide a high-level Python API with GeoJSON.

Of course this only covers the WFS client part of the use case.  Your code would need to cover the change detection / updating case.